# Eclipse Open Type Pick Absolute Match First

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have two classes, `UserServiceDBImpl` and `UsergroupServiceDBImpl`.  When I use the "Open Type" dialog and type in 'UserServiceDBImpl' it often puts `UsergroupServiceDBImpl` first even though the other class is an exact match.

Is there any way to convince Eclipse to put the absolute match ahead of whatever it decides is the "best" solution according to its internal rules?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug report open for this since 2005:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109670

If you include the package when typing the classname into the dialog eg: "*.user.UserServiceDBImpl" it will help narrow it down, at least if the wrong options are in different packages anyway. Tedious though.